# Facebook creating event start_time format issue

Tags: facebook, api, events

I am using FB API for creating events and I have problem with timeformat of start_time. When I use this format:
2013-05-04T09:00:00+0200
witch is relevant to my timezone I am getting back error code 100 about Invalid parameter.

I've tested that a little bit so I know that problem is in "+". When I use this api same way but for any time with "-" (2013-05-04T09:00:00-0200) it works and event is created - of course with wrong time displayed on FB page...

Any ideas? Thank you very much!